# NotebookWrite undo

Tags: evaluation, notebooks

Is there way to make `NotebookWrite`s undooable?

For example let's say I open a new notebook and then run.

```
NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], Cell["New content", "Subsection"]]
```

Is there way to make the text above then dissapear when I hit `Ctrl`+`z`.

Comment: Lol... "Undo"? What's that?

Comment: @rm-rf you are right Mathematica's undo is quit pitful, but typical you have atleast 1 level.  With `NotebookWrite`s it seems you don't even get 1 undo.

Comment: http://i.qkme.me/3qndg9.jpg :o)

Comment: @Liam "1 Level" of undo is very misleading. Try entering `1+1` in a cell (don't evaluate), move down. Now switch to a different notebook and move through a few cells (don't type anything yet). Nothing has changed, right? You didn't even type anything new or evaluate. Go back to your previous notebook and see if you can enjoy your 1 level undo :D This can happen within the same notebook as well. I'd rather they have proper undo support or zero support for undo — caveman style — than play Russian roulette with this nonsense.

Comment: @Nasser good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `NotebookWrite` undoable if you tag the cells that you write (in your example).

```
NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 Cell["New content", "Subsection", CellTags -> {"1"}]]
```

Then to undo:

```
NotebookLocate["1"];
NotebookDelete[InputNotebook[]]
```

More generally

```
i=1;
```

and

```
NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 Cell["New content " <> ToString[i], "Subsection", 
  CellTags -> {ToString[i++]}]]
```

and

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 NotebookEventActions -> {{"KeyDown", 
     "z"} :> (NotebookLocate[ToString[--i]];
     NotebookDelete[InputNotebook[]])}]
```

so when you press "z" the most recent cell you've written would be deleted. Not particularly elegant but probably best you got until proper undo is available (don't hold your breath).

But if write to notebooks and then needing to programmatically make changes is likely to be something you will be doing I see no harm in tagging cells and heading down that path.

Comment: My only issue with using `CellTags` is that they can be shown by the user, so if the user has them turned on, this would create issues. Why not use [`CellID`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellID.html), instead? One possibility is to set `CreateCellID -> True` which guarantees a unique `CellID` for each cell.